# How to read tag names from xml at any depth using xslt and How to segregate all the tag names and use as columns in table for SQL insert statement.?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

How to read tag names from xml at any depth using xslt?

How to segregate all the tag names and use as columns in table for SQL insert statement.

Need xslt to generate insert statement using xml tags as columns to a table

```html
<xxx>
   <123>
        <sss>12</sss>
        <zzz>111</zzz>
           <aaa>
                 <qqq>000</qqq>
                 <q11>000</q12>
                 <q22>333</q22>
             </aaa>
             <bbb>
                    <lll>888</lll>
                    <dd>eee</ddd>
                       <111>
                            <ss1>123</ss1>
                             <vvv>777<vvv>
                         <111>
                  </bbb>
            </123>
</xxx>
```

```
insert into sampletable(sss, zzz, qqq, q11, q22, lll, dd, ss1, vvv) 
values(12, 111, 000, 000, 333, 888, eee, 123, 777).
```

Need output.

Answer (score 0):

The below xpath, after required customization, is that you need:

```
concat(
    'Insert into sampletable(',
    string-join((for $var in //*[not(*)] return name($var)),','),
    ') values(',
    string-join((for $var in //*[not(*)] return $var),','),
    ')')
```

**XSLT-2.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

            <xsl:value-of select="concat(
    'Insert into sample table(',
    string-join((for $var in //*[not(*)] return name($var)),','),
    ') values(',
    string-join((for $var in //*[not(*)] return $var),','),
    ')')"/>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above XSLT, with your input provides the below output:

`Insert into sample table(sss,zzz,qqq,q11,q22,lll,dd,ss1,vvv) values(12,,000,000,333,888,eee,123,777)`

**Explanation**:

With xpath, `for $var in //*[not(*)] return name($var)`, we are iterating on every element in the whole document(that doesn't have a child element) and returning it's `name()`. In the same way, in the later `for` returning the values.

`string-join()` is to concat the sequence of items returned with commas.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. How to retrieve all tag names from xml at any depth?

Comment: A part of the xpath in my answer, `for $var in //*[not(*)] return name($var)` returns the names of the elements with no child elements.

Comment: <xsl:template match="xxx/123">
INSERT INTO XXXXX(
<xsl:for-each select="node()">
  
<!--  <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>-->
  <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
  <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
   <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
     <xsl:text></xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <!--  <xsl:value-of select="."/>-->
</xsl:for-each>  I am getting below response insert into xxx(sss,zzz) values(12,11) how to retrieve all the child elements

Comment: @NareshT I've edited my answer with the XSLT-2.0 code. I hope it helps.